# Stop sharing localStorage among servers behind a reverse-proxy (same-origin passes for all)

Tags: html5, reverse-proxy, sharing, local-storage

Consider two backend servers:

```
https://server1.example.com
https://server2.example.com
```

When accessing these servers directly, they naturally have independent `localStorage` objects, since their origins are different; in this case the hostnames differ.

When I place these servers behind a reverse-proxy, they are accessed as follows:

```
https://proxy.example.com/server1
https://proxy.example.com/server2
```

> To slightly complicate the picture, I have a front-end page on the
>   `proxy`:
>
> ```
> https://proxy.example.com
> ```
>
> This front-end page lists the servers as hotlinks using HTML
>   similar to:
>
> ```
> <a href="https://proxy.example.com/server1/" target="_blank">Server1</a>
> <a href="https://proxy.example.com/server2/" target="_blank">Server2</a>
> ```

Now, each of the servers `proxy`, `server1` and `server2` all pass the `same-origin` test, since they each have `origin=https://proxy.example.com:443`.  Consequently, the `localStorage` object is shared among them and this sharing is confusing the apps on `server1` and `server2`.

Is there a way to disable sharing of `localStorage` between `proxy`, `server1`, and `server2` in this configuration?

If not, are there methods in Javascript that will disable sharing between these entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way as far as I know to have the browser segment localStorage based on anything other than the origin, and there's no way to change the origin other than changing the URL.

If your goal is to segment your stored data by site to avoid conflicts, you'll have to do that manually by assigning each site some unique key under which it can store it's data.

If your goal is to prevent server1 from reading/writing to server2's storage, that won't be possible without changing the server's origins.

Comment: Thanks kicken, that confirms my suspicions too.  I ended up modifying the `localStorage` keys with the reverse-proxy substitute command.  So now, the keys are server-specific.  E.g. a key called `foo` is now subsituted by the reverse-proxy to become `server1_foo` and `server2_foo`.  This fixed the sharing issue.